# Power BI - Same slice for different filters

Tags: powerbi, visualization

On a table os solicitations inside a PowerBI project I have multiple fields that references the same another table of users.

| solicitation_id | category | region | curr_user_responsible | user_solver | solver_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | south | Thomas |  |  |
| 2 | C | north | Maria |  |  |
| 3 | A | south |  | Maria | 2022-10-17 |
| 4 | A | east | Maria |  |  |
| 5 | B | west | Joseph |  |  |
| 6 | C | south | Maria |  |  |
| 7 | C | west |  | Thomas | 2022-10-12 |
| 8 | B | south | Maria |  |  |
| 9 | B | east |  | Joseph | 2022-10-10 |
| 10 | A | north |  | Thomas | 2022-10-09 |
| 11 | C | north | Maria |  |  |

I want an user slice. However, in some visualization I want to slice by "*curr_user_responsible*" columns, and at other, by the "*user_solver*" column.

For example, in a chart I want to show the number of solicitations in each category sliced by *curr_user_responsible*.
In a second chart, I want to show the number of solicitations in each region sliced by *curr_user_responsible*.
For these two, I need to slice by *curr_user_responsible*.

But in another chart I want to show a line couting the number of solutions by date, sliced by *user_solver*. In this case, I need the slice to filter by "*user_solver*".

I don't want to put multiple slicers in same page. Just want to choose the user once.
On this exemple, registers with *curr_user_responsible* filled are with *user_solver* empty, and vice-versa. But this is not a rule. It may occur both fields being filled at same time.

Ps. All the users are listed on another table.

Comment: Search for "power bi role playing dimension"

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a virtual table getting data from the solicitations table with only the *solver* related fields and relate this table with the users table.

solicitation (data from SQL DB)

| solicitation_id | category | region | curr_user_responsible | user_solver | solver_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | south | Thomas |  |  |
| 2 | C | north | Maria |  |  |
| 3 | A | south |  | Maria | 2022-10-17 |
| 4 | A | east | Maria |  |  |
| 5 | B | west | Joseph |  |  |
| 6 | C | south | Maria |  |  |
| 7 | C | west |  | Thomas | 2022-10-12 |
| 8 | B | south | Maria |  |  |
| 9 | B | east |  | Joseph | 2022-10-10 |
| 10 | A | north |  | Thomas | 2022-10-09 |
| 11 | C | north | Maria |  |  |

solicitations solver (data from solicitations table)

| solicitation_id | user_solver | solver_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | Maria | 2022-10-17 |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 | Thomas | 2022-10-12 |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 | Joseph | 2022-10-10 |
| 10 | Thomas | 2022-10-09 |
| 11 |  |  |

User table (data from SQL DB)

| user |
| --- |
| Maria |
| Thomas |
| Joseph |

Relationships

solicitation[curr_user_responsible] <-> user[user]

solicitations solver[user_solver] <-> user[user]

I read about the USERELATIONSHIP function and I understood that it is possible to do this without creating the second table, but I failed to do this. By the way, my solution was enough.